# E: python-setuptools upgrade fails, apt-get broken

Tags: debian, apt, python

I wanted to install gnome-maps with apt-get, and then I got this error:

```
Preparing to unpack .../python-setuptools_3.4.1-1_all.deb ...
Unpacking python-setuptools (3.4.1-1) over (3.3-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python-setuptools_3.4.1-1_all.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/build', which is also in package python-pyaudio 0.2.7-2+b1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-setuptools_3.4.1-1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

It wants to update `python-setuptools` package, but somehow fails,

```
apt-get -f install
apt-get clean
dpkg --configure -a
```

does not help.

When i try to install sth now it says

```
 sudo apt-get install sup
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-setuptools : Depends: python-pkg-resources (= 3.3-1) but 3.4.1-1 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I am running Debian unstable.

/var/log/dpkg.log gives:

```
2014-04-04 13:16:10 startup archives unpack 
2014-04-04 13:16:10 upgrade python-setuptools:all 3.3-1 3.4.1-1 
2014-04-04 13:16:10 status half-configured python-setuptools:all 3.3-1 
2014-04-04 13:16:10 status unpacked python-setuptools:all 3.3-1 
2014-04-04 13:16:10 status half-installed python-setuptools:all 3.3-1 
2014-04-04 13:16:10 status unpacked python-setuptools:all 3.3-1 
2014-04-04 13:16:11 status installed python-setuptools:all 3.3-1
```

complete: [link](http://pastebin.com/HjhqqxZ5)

Comment: What error do you get when you now try to install something?

Comment: Also, please add (or link) your `/var/log/dpkg.log`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it just looks like the `apt-get` exited before it could install the necessary dependencies. Since there don't appear to be any reverse dependencies for `python-setuptools`, I would just try removing it and see what happens:

```
apt-get purge python-setuptools
```

If that doesn't work, then:

```
dpkg -P python-setuptools
```

From there you could try installing again, but from the error message:

```
trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/build', which is also in package python-pyaudio 0.2.7-2+b1
```

it looks like there is a problem with the package. If it happens again you should submit a bug report to Debian.

If it is a problem with the package, then the old one should be somewhere in `/var/cache/apt/archives`. You could just re-install it from there with `dpkg -i`, or if it isn't, it should be in Debian `testing` and downloadable via https://www.debian.org/distrib/packages.

Generally if you are running `unstable`, have the `apt-listbugs` package installed. This will warn if there are any serious bugs reported for any package you try to install. Also consider setting up a mixed `testing`/`unstable` system as issues like this are usually fixed by the time the package reaches `testing` plus you still have access to the raw stuff in unstable.

Comment: Purging did not work, because there was other software that depended on python-setuptools.

The solution was to download the packages
python-setuptools (3.3-1) and
python-pkg-resources (3.3-1) from the testing repo manually, and install them with "dpkg -i <filename of downloaded packages>" After that everything worked fine again. I'm not feeling confident to report a bug, but I will try to figure out if it is one, and how to report it.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @mpt, sorry, my bad. I used the wrong command to list reverse dependencies for `python-setuptools`. Turns out there are loads of reverse dependencies. If you report a bug, it should be easy enough to reproduce (provided it happens again for you), so no-one will say anything untoward. It will also save other people the same issues.

Comment: Yep it happens every time i try to upgrade, did report it.
Thanks again! :-)